# How to access DataInputStream?

Tags: java, android, sockets, byte, inputstream

In my question before, I mentioned, my `OutputStream` would do strange things. that is past now, but suddenly a wild further problem appeared. I do not know, how I can read out my `InputStream`. I had it so far, I could read Byte for Byte, but that is not what i want. I want a variable length-readIn, I mean if 3 Bytes are send i just want to read 3 Bytes, if 9 Bytes are send I want to read 9 Bytes.

*Here's my Code:*

```
package com.example.wettkampftimerbt;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class network extends AsyncTask<URL, String, String> {

    private final String PREFS_NAME = "prefs", W2 = "w2", W3 = "w3", W4 = "w4",
            W5 = "w5", W6 = "w6", SENDBEG = "sendbeg", SENDEND = "sendend";
    int w1, w2, w3, w4, w5, w6, w7, w8, sendend, sendbeg, diny1, diny2, diny3,
            diny4, diny5, diny6, diny7, diny8, dinymin, dinysek, w90, w91, w92,
            w93, w94, w95, w96, w97, netpru, y, retries, length, btw1 = 0,
            btw2 = 0, btw3 = 0, btw4 = 0, btw5 = 0, btw6 = 0, btw7 = 0,
            btw8 = 0, btw9 = 0, btw10 = 0;
    boolean visi1, visi2, visi3, visi4, visi5, visi6, visi7, visi8, login1,
            login2, login3, login4, login5, login6, login7, login8, data;
    Context context;
    private final String LFDNR1 = "lfdnr1";
    private final String LFDNR2 = "lfdnr2";
    private final String LFDNR3 = "lfdnr3";
    private final String LFDNR4 = "lfdnr4";
    private final String LFDNR5 = "lfdnr5";
    private final String LFDNR6 = "lfdnr6";
    private final String LFDNR7 = "lfdnr7";
    private final String LFDNR8 = "lfdnr8", COMMAND = "command", LANE = "lane",
            DINYMIN = "dinymin", DINYSEK = "dinysek";
    Socket sock;
    byte[] btw;
    byte[] bta;




    protected String doInBackground(URL... params) {
        retries = 1;
        try {
            getPrefs(context);
            btw1 = sendbeg;
            btw2 = w2;// to
            btw3 = w3;// from
            btw4 = w4;// lfdnr
            btw5 = w5;// command
            visi(context, false);
            SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress("192.168.0.7", 2001);
            sock = new Socket();
            int timeout = 1000; // 1000 millis = 1 second
            sock.connect(sockaddr, timeout);
            sock.setReuseAddress(true);
            System.out.println(sock);

                        //from here

        if (sock.isConnected()) {
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                    (OutputStream) sock.getOutputStream());
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dis));
            getByte((byte) btw1, (byte) btw2, (byte) btw3, (byte) btw4,
                    (byte) btw5, (byte) btw6, (byte) btw7, (byte) btw8,
                    (byte) btw9, (byte) btw10);
            dos.write(btw, 0, length); 
            int in = rdr.read();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            dis.close();

                                 //to here edited

                System.out.printf("dis: ", btw);
                visi(context, true);
                if (diny5 != 32)
                    System.out.println("ungleich");
                reccom();
                sock.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            System.out.println("IO error " + e + " lulu");
        }

        return "Done";
    }

    private byte[] getByte(byte byte1, byte byte2, byte byte3, byte byte4,
            byte byte5, byte byte6, byte byte7, byte byte8, byte byte9,
            byte byte10) {
        if (byte10 > 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5, byte6, byte7,
                    byte8, byte9, byte10 };
            length = 10;
        } else if (byte9 > 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5, byte6, byte7,
                    byte8, byte9 };
            length = 9;
        } else if (byte8 > 0 && byte9 == 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5, byte6, byte7,
                    byte8 };
            length = 8;
        } else if (byte7 > 0 && byte8 == 0 && byte9 == 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5, byte6, byte7 };
            length = 7;
        } else if (byte6 > 0 && byte7 == 0 && byte8 == 0 && byte9 == 0
                && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5, byte6 };
            length = 6;
        } else if (byte5 > 0 && byte6 == 0 && byte7 == 0 && byte8 == 0
                && byte9 == 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4, byte5 };
            length = 5;
        } else if (byte4 > 0 && byte5 == 0 && byte6 == 0 && byte7 == 0
                && byte8 == 0 && byte9 == 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3, byte4 };
            length = 4;
        } else if (byte3 > 0 && byte4 == 0 && byte5 == 0 && byte6 == 0
                && byte7 == 0 && byte8 == 0 && byte9 == 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2, byte3 };
            length = 3;
        } else if (byte2 > 0 && byte3 == 0 && byte4 == 0 && byte5 == 0
                && byte6 == 0 && byte7 == 0 && byte8 == 0 && byte9 == 0
                && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1, byte2 };
            length = 2;
        } else if (byte1 > 0 && byte2 == 0 && byte3 == 0 && byte4 == 0
                && byte5 == 0 && byte6 == 0 && byte7 == 0 && byte8 == 0
                && byte9 == 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] { byte1 };
            length = 1;
        } else if (byte1 == 0 && byte2 == 0 && byte3 == 0 && byte4 == 0
                && byte5 == 0 && byte6 == 0 && byte7 == 0 && byte8 == 0
                && byte9 == 0 && byte10 == 0) {
            btw = new byte[] {};
            length = 0;
        }
        return btw;
    }


    public void onPreExecute(Context context) {
        System.out.println("network_onPreExecute");
        getPrefs(context);
    }

    public void getPrefs(Context context) {
        w2 = 0;
        w3 = 0;
        w4 = 0;
        w5 = 0;
        w6 = 0;
        System.out.println("network_getPrefs");
        System.out.println(context);
        w2 = Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W2, "03"));
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(W2).commit();
        w3 = Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W3, "00"));
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(W3).commit();
        w4 = Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W4, "00"));
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(W4).commit();;
        w5 = Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W5, "49"));
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(W5).commit();
        w6 = Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(W6, "00"));
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(W6).commit();
        sendbeg = Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SENDBEG, "00"));
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(SENDBEG).commit();
        sendend = Integer.valueOf(context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getString(SENDEND, "00"));
        context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().remove(SENDEND).commit();
    }

    public network(Context context) {
        System.out.println("network_Context");
        onPreExecute(context);
        this.context = context;
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
}
```

Im even thankful for code optimizing-tips.

Comment: did you get method `getByte(...)` from http://thedailywtf.com/ ?

Comment: nope :D accidantally the same name :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try(FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(accountFile);
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
   )
{
    String in = rdr.readLine();
}
```

this is part of my project what is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: my eclipse says `Resource specification not allowed here for source level below 1.7` so it seems i need another way

Comment: a little bit modified and eclipse agrees with it, but i still have no input

Comment: ill add it to my question marked it with //from here //to here edited

Comment: As it doesn't use DataInputStream and it doesn't read exactly 3 bytes, it isn't what he needs at all. Not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are looking for is `DataInputStream.readFully().`

Comment: @Ekonion Eh? Have a look at the API. It takes a `byte[]` argument. That's where 'what was read in' goes. Surprised to be asked such a trivial question that is already answered in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation and are are no friends.. it's sometimes hard for me to understand it... dunno why, but thx ^^

Comment: @EJP I always see people doing things like a while(bytesRead != -1) inputStream.read(buffer); - why would I do that if I can just use this readFully() function?